# bind parser returning wrong type

Tags: haskell

I am reading haskell book and curious why the return type of the bind operator look odd to me

For the given definitions

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a, String)]

item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of 
                   [] -> []
                   (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]

bind :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
p `bind` f = \inp -> concat [ f x inp' | (x, inp') <- p inp]
```

when I define z in GHCI as

```
let z = item `bind` (\x -> (\y -> result (x,y))) "Rohit"
```

the return type is

```
>> :t z
z :: Parser ([Char], Char)
```

Question:
(1) Shouldn't the return type of (Char, [Char])? looking at the list comprehension, "(x, inp') <- p inp" should yield -> "('r', "ohit")". Next f x inp' is left associative, so f x should yield character 'r' and pass to the lambda that should return result tuple ('r', "ohit"), but why is it that z type is ([Char], char) :: (x,y)

(2) How can i print the value of z in the above case on the ghci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `result` is of type `a -> [a]` (did you mean `return` for the list monad?), the issue you encounter comes from the fact that you use the infix `bind`.

```
item `bind` (\x -> (\y -> result (x,y))) "Rohit"
```

is parsed as

```
bind item ((\ x y -> result (x, y)) "Rohit")
```

rather than what you expected which I assume is:

```
bind item (\ x y -> result (x, y)) "Rohit"
```

You can fix this by using `$`:

```
let z = item `bind` (\x -> (\y -> result (x,y))) $ "Rohit"
```

Comment: I tried as suggested but got the below exception *Main> let z = item `bind` (\x -> (\y -> result (x,y))) $ "Rohit"

<interactive>:89:35:
    Couldn't match type `String -> [((Char, String), String)]'
                  with `[(b0, String)]'
    Expected type: [(b0, String)]
      Actual type: Parser (Char, String)
    In the return type of a call of `result'
    Probable cause: `result' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: result (x, y)
    In the expression: (\ y -> result (x, y))

Comment: What is the type of `result`? It is not defined in your snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure what `result` is here, but this is a problem of associativity. Consider your `z`:

```
let z = item `bind` (\x -> (\y -> result (x,y))) "Rohit"
```

This is equivalent to

```
let z = item `bind` ((\x -> (\y -> result (x,y))) "Rohit")
      = item `bind` (\y -> result ("Rohit",y))
```

I believe you would get the result you desire by adding the following brackets:

```
let z = (item `bind` (\x -> (\y -> result (x,y)))) "Rohit"
```

Comment: Main> let z = (item `bind` (\x -> (\y -> result (x,y)))) "Rohit"

<interactive>:91:36:
    Couldn't match type `String -> [((Char, String), String)]'
                  with `[(b0, String)]'
    Expected type: [(b0, String)]
      Actual type: Parser (Char, String)
    In the return type of a call of `result'
    Probable cause: `result' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: result (x, y)
    In the expression: (\ y -> result (x, y))